# Can it make sense to call one overloaded constructor from another?

Tags: delphi, constructor, overloading

If I have two overloaded constructors, one without and one with parameters:

```
constructor Create; overload;
constructor Create(Param: TObject); overload;
```

If I want the code in the first one to run, does it make sense to call it within the second one? And inherited to call the parent constructor first as well?

```
constructor TMyType.Create(Param: TObject);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Create;
  FParam := Param;
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: How can we possibly know whether or not that makes sense? We cannot see all the code. Perhaps you have some good reason to do this. That said, I can think of no good reason, so I predict that the code is bogus.

Comment: Yes, it is common practice to call one simpler constructor from another more complex constructor.
However, it's not that easy as you present it: to avoid duplicated inherited calls.

Answer (score 0):

> If I want the code in the first one to run, does it make sense to call it within the second one **And** inherited to call the parent constructor first as well?

No. Because your 1st constructor should call inherited one itself, so in the end the inherited constructor would get called twice, which it most probably does not expect.

Otherwise, if your parameterless `TMyType.Create()` does not call inherited one, then it is hardly a proper constructor and should be just removed.

So the correct approach would be like that:

```
constructor TMyType.Create(Param: TObject); overload;
begin
  Create();
  FParam := Param;
end;

constructor TMyType.Create();  overload;
begin
  inherited Create(); // for both constructors

  ...some common code
end;
```

However in Delphi there is yet another possibility.

```
constructor Create; overload;
constructor Create(Param: TObject); overload;
procedure AfterConstruction; override;


constructor TMyType.Create(Param: TObject); 
begin
  inherited Create(); 

  FParam := Param;
end;

constructor TMyType.Create();
begin
  inherited ; 

 ... maybe some extra code
end;

procedure TMyType.AfterConstruction();
begin
    inherited;

  ...some common code
end;
```

Note the difference though, when would "common code" be executed and when would do "FParam := Param;"

In the 1st way, the flow would be like

- Create (Param)
- ..Create()
- ....Inherited Create()
- ....**Common Code**
- ..**FParam := Param;**
- *AfterConstruction (empty)*

In the second the sequence would be different

- Create(Param) or Create()
- ..Inherited Create()
- ..**FParam := Param;**
- AfterConstruction
- ..**Common Code**

As you can see the order of those chunks being executed got reversed.

---

However maybe you don't need multiple constructors at all?

```
constructor TMyType.Create(const Param: TObject = nil); 
begin
  inherited; 

 ... Some code

  FParam := Param;
end;
```

Comment: Confusing to have an implicit `AfterConstruction`. Better to put common part in a method and call from both constructors.

Comment: And then you have 10 constructors with non-trivial dependency graph, but that is still easy. Yet in 2 years another guy makes grand-grand-grand child if your class and suddenly things got mixed. YMMV,  but I consider AfterConstruction a very cool feature

Comment: This is just too long of an answer for what should be a simple no, don't do it. If there's code to be executed in both constructors then that specific code should reside in a dedicated method which can be called from both constructors.

Comment: My understanding is the purpose of `AfterConstruction` is to call code that cannot run in the constructor. This was introduced to overcome differences between Delphi and C++Builder because of differences in virtual methods handling (TCustomForm and similar use in components).

Comment: @petervonča be it so,  Delphi would not allow constructors to be called as methods.

Comment: @lurd so it ended being more versatile tool than intended ;-)

Comment: It will make proofreading an art better suited balded people.

Comment: @LURD Indeed. Delphi's design is crazy in that it performs polymorphic method dispatch in constructors.

Comment: @lurd then one should disable having multiple constructors. However if you allow them to exists,  then a predefined uniform invariant that AfterConstruction is is easier than an ad hoc non uniform cross-constructors dependencies

Comment: Multiple constructors are ok, as is object inheritance. But having to check implicit AfterConstruction just for the sake of keeping the DRY principle is the wrong way to design objects.

Comment: And copy-pasting the call of ad hoc AC, then later adding yet another constructor forgetting to call it, then refactoring forgetting to replace the call in all but one constructors is better? It is no more implicit than TWinControl.CreateParams

Comment: @LURD did you saw mantra that constructor should not have any other code than initializing properties with its parameters? IOW a proper constructor is but syntactic sugar. For everything else there are methods like Application.Initialize. Like if we have explicit TQuery.Open it is bad that TFileStream is implicitly opened without calling Open. That makes a point. If you have no way to ensure your children can easily add more initialization constructors that would still end in your own post-init routine, then the extensibility is made complex and fragile, making necessary "no code in ctors"

Comment: OTOH that is still not enough. If the constructor is doing anything, then it means it knows something about the situation outside the object it belongs in. Which is called "leaky abstraction". In a language properly made there would be no constructors, and when you need to create an object for use in a proper environment, you just take it from environment-aware Class Factory. And if there is another situation where the object can be used, you take the object from another Class Factory.  It is as [easy as breathing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html).

Answer (score -3):

**Yes your code makes perfect sense and the constructor's calls do exactly what one should expect.**

Delphi object model supports both constructors that call inherited constructors and constructors that do not call inherited ones.

If you are not sure try this:

```
program Project5;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TMyBase = class
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TMyType = class(TMyBase)
    constructor Create; overload;
    constructor Create(Param: TObject); overload;
  end;

constructor TMyBase.Create;
begin
  Writeln('TMyBase.Create');
end;

constructor TMyType.Create;
begin
  Writeln('TMyType.Create');
end;

constructor TMyType.Create(Param: TObject);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Create;
  Writeln('TMyType.Create(Param)');
end;

begin
  TMyType.Create(TObject.Create);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: A constructor that does not call `inherited` is not a proper constructor.  Both constructors need to call `inherited`.  If a constructor need to call another constructor then do not call `inherited` in the first constructor, let the second constructor call it. The way Arioch'The describes it is the correct way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - A constructor that does not call `inherited` is as good as the one that calls it as much as Delphi concerned. We discuss Delphi here and not an imaginary perfect programming language

Comment: Either you follow common sense and traditional idea of inheritance ( with inherited constructors being used) or you are to give your own non-standard definition for "makes sense"

Comment: @Arioch'The C++ does not use inherited constructors at all. Delphi can do without inherited constructors too, without problems.

Comment: So your definition of "make sense" is "can write C++ code in Delphi". Not a lot of sense in my book,.  In C++ you can write C++ code better.

Comment: 1st you learn the rules, 2nd you use and understand the rules, 3rd you bend and abuse them. You're suggesting level 3 tricks to a novice,  who obviously is still at level zero. That would just blow his mind rather than actually teach him a thing.

Comment: @Serg It doesn't make a lot of sense to skip base class constructors. What state do you expect your object to be in when that is done. Yes you can do it, but generally you should not.

Comment: OK it does not make sense in terms of good object design but it makes clear sense in terms of the Delphi language; and a Delphi programmer should know the Delphi language as is IMO.

Comment: @user246408: in the code you showed, `TMyType.Create()` does not call `inherited`, only `TMyType.Create(TObject)` calls `inherited`, so if the user constructs a `TMyType` using the `Create()` constructor then `inherited` is never called. That is a problem if the `TMyBase` constructor needs to initialize anything. And FYI, C++11 adds delegating constructors so a constructor can now call another constructor of the same class.

Comment: "it makes clear sense in terms of the Delphi language" In terms of the language the only thing that makes sense is "successfully compiles". If the program is compiled then (except for bugs) it does what it is intended to do ("intended" == "the sources instruct program to do it"). Which becomes somewhat too trivial. All the patterns exist not for "that can be compiled in given language" but because it is believed that is most efficient/problemless way to solve a practical problem. Showing "you can compile this code" without telling why it is good or bad is about learning, yet not about "sense"

Comment: @RemyLebeau  "That is a problem if the TMyBase constructor needs to initialize anything" but then TMyType.Create maybe can initialize all that needs to be initialized directly, and then inherited constructor really might be not needed. That is possible in some cases to come out with a scheme like this. And Delphi language - sure - allows that way. However that is level 3 - abusing the rules intentionally and responsibly. Surely teaching the newb to shoot between the fingers would only end him shooting the leg. But someday hopefully topicstarter would understand enough to really try it

Comment: @Arioch'The: It is not good practice to have a derived constructor initialize ancestor members directly, that is the base constructor's responsibility.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree.  Generally it is bad idea. But every rule has exceptions. That is when we come to level 3. However for TopicStarter it was way too early to think of abominations like that.